while starting the react project and build fails when i run "npx react-native run -android"
**I am on LINUX and have java version 22 **
REACT NATIVE
The project has ben created and when i run start command and choose android then this reason is shown and the build fails:

What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/home/aditya/REACT/Project01/android/settings.gradle' (/home/aditya/.gradle/caches/8.3/scripts/3d7wkqomry2qguq2ifbq4t7xf).


BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 66

I was expecting for the ap to show up on the phone which i have conected
Also i made a project by this same process and i changed nothing and that project did not show any errors
